# forbidden: User , "code": 403 error while accessing kube-apiserver using curl

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kube-apiserver

Kubernetes version : v1.19.0

I have created a user and performed clusterrolebinding with a role cluster-admin.

```
[root@project1-master ~]# kubectl describe clusterrole cluster-admin
Name:         cluster-admin
Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  *.*        []                 []              [*]
             [*]                []              [*]

[root@project1-master ~]# kubectl describe clusterrolebinding sajeesh  cluster-admin
Name:         sajeesh
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cluster-admin
Subjects:
  Kind  Name     Namespace
  ----  ----     ---------
  User  sajeesh


Name:         cluster-admin
Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cluster-admin
Subjects:
  Kind   Name            Namespace
  ----   ----            ---------
  Group  system:masters
```

> > I am able to run kubectl with this useraccount and get pods information :

```
[root@project1-master ~]# kubectl get pods --as sajeesh
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busyb   1/1     Running   3          21h
```

> > But when i try to access kube-apiserver using curl it show forbidden error as following :

```
[root@project1-master ~]# curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert sajeesh.crt --key sajeesh.key https://$IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/busyb
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods \"busyb\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "busyb",
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
```

> > I have re-verified the cacert , cert & key i am providing with that user account .They are correct.

> > Any suggestions why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally managed to findout the problem.it is not related to kubernetes but with curl command i am using .

```
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert sajeesh.crt --key sajeesh.key https://$IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/busyb
```

when i used -v switch along with command , It showed :

```
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
  CApath: none
* warning: certificate file name "sajeesh.crt" handled as nickname; please use "./sajeesh.crt" to force file name
* NSS: client certificate not found: newsajeesh.crt
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

So basically it was looking for absolute path as input for arguments --cert & --key

```
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert ./sajeesh.crt --key ./sajeesh.key https://$IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/busyb
```

after giving  the absolute path it worked fine and i am able to get the output.

Answer (score 1):

The clusterrolebinding `sajeesh` has name `sajeesh` and Group `system:masters`.Hence the certificate need to have `sajeesh` as Common Name(CN) and   `system:masters` as Organization(O). When the request goes to kubernetes API server it will inspect the certificate and match `CN` with `name` and `O` with `Group` in `clusterrolebinding` and if it does not match you get `403 Forbidden` error.

You can verify above by running below command

```
openssl x509 -in sajeesh.crt -text -noout
```

Comment: Yes CN is sajeesh , But O is different becuase i want this user to be a part of different group named group1. 

Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=kubernetes
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 12 07:44:59 2020 GMT
            Not After : Sep 12 07:44:59 2021 GMT
        Subject: CN=sajeesh, O=group1

Comment: As I said `O` need to have `system:masters` because that's what you have in the clusterrolebinding..otherwise edit or create a new clusterrolebinding with `Group` `group1`

Comment: if you see the output of 'kubectl describe clusterrolebinding sajeesh  cluster-admin' in my question ,  Binding is done to both user name sajeesh and also to group system:masters.so ideally it should provided access to this user as well and one more reason to support this thought is "kubectl get pods --as sajeesh" is working fine .

Comment: I have recreated the user(csr&certificate) Mentioning O as system:masters 

        Issuer: CN=kubernetes
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 12 15:50:00 2020 GMT
            Not After : Sep 12 15:50:00 2021 GMT
        Subject: CN=sajeesh, O=system:masters

It is still showing same error when i access it using curl .

"message": "pods \"busyb\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\""

Comment: Can you check the client certificate that you have in kubeconfig. Compare that with the generated certificate and see if there is any difference other than the CN